# Paypal Pro Instant Payment Notifications

Tags: paypal, paypal-pro, ipn

I have set up paypal pro following all the info re API etc but I am getting the following message from paypal everyday

Is this an error in my magento back end or something I have done wrong in my paypal account?

What should my URL in the paypal back end be?

```
Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications
(IPN). Instant Payment Notifications sent to the following URL(s) are
failing:
```

Answer (score 3):

Magento sends notify_url for IPN messages which overrides IPN settings specified in your PayPal account. It seems that you have wrong url in your PP Profile - You can turn off IPN in the Profile and you will still receive IPNs from PayPal if using Magento. See more details on this in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/ , section Dynamically Setting the Notification URL